# ASP.NET MVC - Adding multiple items to a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, dynamic

I've got the next question about the right way of adding items to a list in MVC.

Let's say I got the following model:

```
public class Student
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm in the Student Create view in which the user can add multiple Lessons. The way the view looks is that there is a dropdown in which you can select a lesson and a button to add a new dropdown. This way a person can add multiple lessons to the Lessons variable.

Now I tried alot of different approaches but never seemed to have the right one because I don't like having this in the view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Lessons[0].Id, new SelectList(...), "Select lesson")
```

And change the 0 to 1..2 etc with jquery or what so ever.

What are your approaches on those views in which you dynamicly add multiple items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at defining an editor template:

If you write your template correctly, asp.net will render controls with the names similar to:

```
Lesson[0]_Title
```

**UPDATE:** Here's how:

Create a folder in views\shared called EditorTemplates
Then create a partial view with a model of type Lesson inside here. Make sure you call this partial view "Lesson.cshtml" (or ascx if you're not using razor)

Then you can do...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lessons)
```

...and asp.net will magically figure out that because Lessons is an IEnumerable of lesson, it should loop and render an editor for each one. Pretty neat!

Some links:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1846290.aspx/1?Editor+template+of+type+IEnumerable+SelectListItem+with+MVC+area

Comment: That would be a nice solution. Though we need the right template then indeed. It would be awesome if you could find the link you're talking about!

Comment: I'm struggling actually... I'm going to see if I can knock up an example quickly myself...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the EditorTemplates. Though if a new Student is made we don't know how many Lessons he will follow. So we should be able to dynamicly add new Editors for the Lessons.

Comment: Yes sorry... I have provided an update that is not strictly what you asked for, but should be a simpler way of achieveing it. Say you wanted to add x number of lessons, you can then prepopulate that number of lessons in the model, and it will provide an editor for each one which you can save in a single form. It's a little confusing so feel free to ask if you have more questions.

Comment: Alternatively there is a very nice solution that can be achieved using jquery and knockout to dynamically create\remove new lessons and then still have it compatible with .net when you submit the form, that I will be blogging about this weekend.

Comment: No problem Roysvork, I like the energy you are putting in to this. But indeed I don't know how many lessons a student will follow. So whenever he presses a button like "add lesson" there should appear a new dropdown under the others which will also be added to the list.

Comment: If you would blog an example that would be really awesome! I'll be waiting for it!

Comment: Understandable! If you want a quick solution in the meantime, you can always ask the user up front how many they want and do a trip back to the server to recalculate... bit clunky but it would work.

Comment: The problem is that the customer already delivered the way they want the "screens" to work. But I'll wait for your post or somebody else with a nice solution. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I have added another answer with link to blog post. Hope you get this message.